# New index folder while building

Tags: indexing, xcode9

When I run a project using Xcode9, I generate an index folder in the current path of the project, which makes me pay attention to this index every time I submit the code.

[image: screenshot]

What is the Index?

How can I ignore it when I push my code?

Comment: how can i ignore it when i push my code?     

edit .gitignore:

`Index/ `

Comment: solve the problem ：https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49377112/how-do-we-can-stop-auto-created-index-and-build-folder-in-xcode-project-it-tak