# How do we can stop auto created Index and Build folder in xcode project ? It takes lots of extra space for every xcode project folder

Tags: xcode

When I created any new Xcode project and open it then build and index folder automatically created under the project folder. I attached a picture one of my Xcode projects. It must be some Xcode setting, please help if someone already find the problem regarding the same issue.
[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution for this problem by going Xcode preference and change the build location custom to shared build folder. It was selected as the relative path to the workspace before.

[screenshot to build location path change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/40VCA.png)